# lazy loading mutiple contexts in webpack

Tags: webpack

I want to load 2 modules from 2 different contexts (possibly in a single chunk) **after** I've read the navigator.language, so I suppose I have to lazy load, this is working:

```
 var loadData = require('bundle?lazy&name=intl!react-intl/locale-data/' + navigator.language + '.js');
 var loadTranslation = require('bundle?lazy&name=intl!translantion/' + navigator.language + '.js');

 loadData (function (a) {
   loadTranslation (function (b) {
      console.log('I can\'t believe I have to do this to wait for ', a, b);
   }
 });
```

But I was hoping for better syntax,
I have tried with require.ensure, and also with

```
require(['bundle?lazy!react-intl/locale-data/' + navigator.language + '.js','bundle?lazy!translantion/' + navigator.language + '.js'], 
  function (a, b) {
    console.log('what am I doing wrong?');
});
```

but either I get the "require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted", or the messages are not there yet when I render, any idea?